# Como estruturar dados para JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho o retorno de uma query que me trás os seguintes itens a partir da seguinte query (OBS : são tabelas criadas para exemplos)

```
 select * from alunos a left join financs f on f.aluno_id = a.id left join financ_detalhes fd on fd.financ_id = f.id
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero fazer é estruturar isso para json a partir do php para que fique desta forma:

```
{
  "aluno": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "nome": "felipe",
      "nr_cpf": "11111",
      "situação": "A",
      "financeiro": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "dt_pag": "2018-04-10",
          "situacao": "p",
          "descricao": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "descricao": "olá chefe"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "descricao": "olá jurubeba"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "dt_pag": "2018-04-10",
          "situacao": "p",
          "descricao": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "nome": "jose",
      "nr_cpf": "2222",
      "situação": "A",
      "financeiro": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "dt_pag": "2018-04-10",
          "situacao": "p",
          "descricao": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tentei de todas as formas possíveis mas não consigo, alguém tem alguma dica ou sabe como posso fazer?

Momento onde desisti temporariamente:

```
 foreach($alunosBase as $index=>$aluno) {

   $financeiroDesc[$index][] = ['detalhes_id' => $aluno['detalhes_id'],'detalhes_descricao' => $aluno['detalhes_descricao']];

    if(!in_array($aluno['id_financ'],$mapRegFinan)) {
       $financeiro[$index][] = ['id_financ' => $aluno['id_financ'], 'dt_pag'=> $aluno['dt_pag']];
       $mapRegFinan['id_financ'] = $aluno['id_financ'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi direito sua pergunta, mas se você quer transformar tudo em JSON basta utilizar a função `json_encode()` e depois exibi-la na tela.

Comment: Opa...sim isso é verdade só que se eu aplicar diretamente o json_encode o retorno ficara igual a imagem no link -> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsJhC3MhfSGgaqyTQsKfyI58Dn4
o resultado é dois registro se repetindo mudando apenas os registro da tabela de descrição, é por que é um inner join.
Acredito que o certo seria ficar dessa forma na imagem->https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsJhC3MhfSGgaxvlCaxmyJRZ6QI
O registro apenas uma vez e oq é diferente ganha um novo ramo.
Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Se estiver usando PDO use [PDOStatement::fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchobject.php), se estiver usando mysqli use [mysqli_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) para buscar os dados do banco, então use `var_dump` para imprimir na tela e poste na pergunta o resultado